# Arduino Mini Pro 3.3V does not use 1.1V internal reference for ADC

Tags: arduino, adc

Using the Arduino Mini Pro 3.3V I just stumbled over a problem when switching between the "INTERNAL" and "DEFAULT" voltage reference for the ADC.
I want to measure the output of a voltage divider [GND - 110kOhm - A2 - 500kOhm - VCC] for calculating VCC. VCC has been measured as 3.3V. It is provided by a voltage regulator.

In the loop I firstly measure the voltage divider output with the internal reference and afterwards with the default voltage reference.
I saw code examples where people recommend to wait some milliseconds before reading the next value and the  ([analogReference() documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference)) recommends to  ignore the first readings after calling analogReference(). I follow these guidlines.

I'll provide a minimum example sketch:

```
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup()
{
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);    // ADC pin
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("----------------");
}

void burn8Readings(int pin)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    analogRead(pin);
  }
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop()
{
  uint16_t nResult1, nResult2;

  analogReference(INTERNAL);    // set the ADC reference to 1.1V
  delay(10);                    // idle some time
  burn8Readings(A2);            // make 8 readings but don't use them to ensure good reading after ADC reference change

  nResult1 = analogRead(A2);    // read actual value

  analogReference(DEFAULT);     // set the ADC reference back to internal for other measurements
  delay(10);                    // idle again
  burn8Readings(A2);            // make 8 readings but don't use them to ensure good reading after ADC reference change

  nResult2 = analogRead(A2);    // do other measurements

// print result to serial interface..
  Serial.print("1: ");  
  Serial.print(nResult1);
  Serial.print(" - 2: ");
  Serial.println(nResult2);

  delay(2000);
}
```

The first pair of ADC results seems correct (553 / 184), but in the following iterations the first value is faulty without changing the actual voltage on the ADC pin. (240 / 183)
The ADC result of the DEFAULT reference is always fine.

For a 2.56V reference the value of 240 would be feasible. I know that some ATmegas use a 2.56V reference voltage, but the ATmega328 should have 1.1V only. Strangely the  ([ATmega328/P datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf)) mentions a 2.56V reference in an ADC example in chapter 28.7, so I'm confused.

Is there a possibility there is a 2.56V ADC reference in a certain ATmega328p version?

Comment: Just one comment: why do you have to change the voltage reference during execution? I think that if your application requires a precise reference then you have to set it to internal for all your measures (and so set the reference in the setup and never change it)

Comment: In my minimum example sketch I just measured VCC twice. There I have to admit I don't know a reason why to switch the reference voltage.
In my actual application I want to read out other sensors which act as a voltage divider between GND and VCC. Using the same VCC as reference voltage of the ADC allows me to interpret the measurements independently of the actual VCC.

Comment: and then you also have to measure something with a more stable reference.. That is totally reasonable. Thank you

Comment: Yes, the measurement with the more stable reference actually indeed is the battery VCC. I want to monitor the battery voltage as it drops.

Comment: Then can't you use the Vcc as reference voltage and measure the "stable" reference? You will get the inverse of the voltage, but with a simple mathematical operation you will get the voltage without the need of a resistor divider to get a fraction of the battery voltage

Comment: You again are totally right and again I skipped a crucial detail: There  (probably) will be a voltage regulator/booster (pololu) after the battery. I monitor the battery voltage, whereas the actual Arduino VCC is more or less constant. So I cannot directly take the Arduino VCC as reference. The AREF pin is not used at the arduino Pro Mini, so I also cannot connect VCC_bat directly.
I'm not in favor of the booster as they seem inefficent to me and their gain small for battery powered applications in the 1mA range. (probably smaller than their power consumption) But it's not only my decision.

Comment: That again is a totally reasonable reason ;) as for the booster, according to my experience it depends on the battery. For lithium rechargeable batteries (li-ion or li-po) they are not very useful (if you can deal with the varying input voltage); for alkhaline they are optional; for lithium coin cells (e.g. CR2032) they are really helpful, especially when you have current pulses (for instance on remote controllers), because they have very poor performances. And for small currents use small converters: they will be optimized (I tend to use charge pumps for these, like the MAX1595)

Comment: We have not decided on the batteries yet, although I am aware it is closely related to the choice of regulator. Rechargable batteries are preferred. It is likely we will use LSD-NiMH batteries. Coin cells are interesting because of their small size. I figured zinc-air bateries are nice because of their stable voltage. (no regulator needed, but not rechargable). But besides our small standby current (~0.2mA) we have data transmission intervals (< 1s @ 15-20mA every hour). That seems to be too high for zinc-air. Also I've never seen a coin cell charger so far, although there are some online.

Comment: Li-Ion/Po batteries need discharge protection and they don't like low temperatures. It would be nice to use the node also outdoors so the temperature could drop to -10 degrees.
I don't have too much experience with the battery jungle, but for me it seems LSD-NiMH have sufficient capacity, peak performance and a low self discharge to ensure long recharge cycles and endure low temperatures. I thought of using either 4 of them together with a MCP1700-3302E to regulate to stable 3.3V, or 2/3 LSD-NiMH with a 3.3V Step-Up/Step-Down Regulator from Pololu. But I'm open to other ideas ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The MCP1700 has 1.6 μA quiescent current, while the MAX1595 is stated with 220µA, the MAX1759 still with 50µA. The Pololu also seemed to be more inefficient with previous setups, but I didn't measure it for the current one. So I think the MCP consumes less overall.
How do boosters help with current pulses? With their capacitors/inductors? For how big pulses does that work?

Comment: well, I have not designed a lot of low power devices, but once I designed a wireless sensor with a CR2032 battery and the first version was not working, because the lithium coin cell batteries have a very high output resistance, so when you try to pull a high (>5-10mA) current they will lower the output voltage. What I did was to put a charge pump (a switching conv would have been fine too, but CP are smaller) and a bulk capacitor (I think 100uF, but make some calculations) and this was enough to smooth the current peaks and make it work. As for the other, I prefer li-ion or li-po ...

Comment: ... since they have a higher power/size ratio. You can buy the size you prefer, the protection circuit is just a comparator (turn everything off if the voltage is too low), charging circuit can be easily done with small components (in the past I used a MAX1555, simply attach it to USB and it charges the li-ion/li-po cell). As for the MCP1700, it is a LDO, so only voltage decrease, while the charge pumps can also raise the voltage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the similarity to the 2.56V was a coincidence and probably an error in the datasheet (or in my understanding).
The problem was that after the analogReference(INTERNAL) call the ADC value has to be read immediately! Not after some milliseconds as I did it. ([Source](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=208389.0))

Still it is important to also wait some milliseconds after doing the dummy readout. For me one readout and delay(5) was just enough, but I guess that depends on the charge left in the capacitor of the ADC: So I'd recommend higher delays.

The correct sequence is:

```
  analogReference(INTERNAL);    // set the ADC reference to 1.1V
  burn8Readings(A2);            // make 8 readings but don't use them
  delay(10);                    // idle some time
  nResult1 = analogRead(A2);    // read actual value
```

and

```
  analogReference(DEFAULT);     // set the ADC reference back to internal
  burn8Readings(A2);            // make 8 readings but don't use them
  delay(10);                    // idle again
  nResult2 = analogRead(A2);    // read actual value
```

Changing the reference back to DEFAULT seems to be less prone...but at least one readout still was necessary for precise results.

I hope no one has to spend time on this one anymore...